# Strings from strings.xml available in application but not used by widgets

Tags: android, string, text, android-resources

I have been making an Android app. Android Studio rightly scolds me if I hardcode strings in the layout editor, so I put them in `res/values/strings.xml`. For a simplified example:

```xml
<resources>
    <string name="thing">Do a thing</string>
</resources>
```

I then set a button's `text` property to `@string/thing`. This correctly displays "Do a thing" in the layout editor, as expected. However, when I actually load my app on my phone with the default Run or Debug commands in Android Studio, the button is blank. This is interesting, as when I manually invoke `resources.getString(R.string.thing)`, I do get `"Do a thing"` back.

I can manually set the widgets' text fields this way, by doing acrobatics like:

```
findViewById<Button>(R.id.myButton).text = resources.getString(R.string.thing)
```

but this is a lot of work that as far as I know should be done automatically. This has happened to me in a Java app too, so the problem isn't Kotlin-specific. I'm using Android Studio 3.6 on Linux and the device is a Redmi Note 3 Pro with LineageOS 16 (Pie).
The button is also blank when the app is launched in a virtual AVD, so clearly I must be doing something wrong.
[Here are the full activity layout and string XML files.](https://gist.github.com/oreganoli/d65179b119277f5f82ed1d83995addd2)

Comment: Could you edit your question and post the complete layout where you are referring to `@string/thing`?

Comment: @CommonsWare Sure, I've linked to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of your `Button` widgets has `tools:text` instead of `android:text`:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/nextButton"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    tools:text="@string/nav_next" />
```

`android:text` is used for fixed text to be displayed at runtime and, by default, in the development tools.

`tools:text` is for sample text to be displayed in development tools only. Mostly that is for cases where the text that you really want to use is not known until runtime (e.g., needs to be loaded from a database). Using `tools:text` lets you get a sense of what the layout will really look like in the tools, while not pre-populating that text when your app runs.

So, switch from `tools:text` to `android:text` and you should get the results that you seek.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it! The source of my confusion was that the tools text field in Android Studio has a wrench icon next to it, and from my experience with Visual Studio, where a wrench symbol means "property" I assumed this meant the value would be dynamic, while the plain un-wrenched field was for hardcoded strings only.

Comment: @oreganoli: In Studio, the wrench means "the equivalent property in the `tools` namespace". It also means "this is why some people just use the XML and skip the properties pane". :-)